# Windows 7 BSOD No Filehandle release & Bugcheck 0x3B

Tags: windows-7, windows, bsod

I got a weird BSOD on my windows box (multiple times, Windows 7). This happens when I'm programming, and trying to compile my code, but as it appears it can't lock the filehandle and write to it.
This normally happens when the process is still executing, but it is clearly not and I need to close the filehandle through the Advanced Taskmanager (Search for "Programname.exe" and close the handle under the allmighty process "SYSTEM"). This happened to me while writing Code in C++, C# and as I remember right, Java aswell.

### Details of the BSOD

It occured for example this night/morning three times.
The Bug Check Code is "3B" ("SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION")
WinDbg says:

```
Probably caused by : ntkrnlmp.exe ( nt!ApphelpBufferWorkItem+15d )
DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT
```

The process name is in two Minidumps chrome.exe and in the third one svchost.exe.

```
1: kd> !memusage
Search: READ_PVOID error 
InitTypeRead(nt!MmPhysicalMemoryBlock, nt!_PHYSICAL_MEMORY_DESCRIPTOR) error 1
```

Please ask, if you need more information.
One thing I did was the memtest86+ RAM check, but all tests were without errors (~3 hours).
I dont really know what the problem is, please help me.